# How to fix this Haskell lookup function type mismatch?

Tags: function, haskell, lookup, type-mismatch, algebraic-data-types

If someone could lend a hand fixing this error, it would be much appreciated. The code is:

```hs
type Name = String
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)
type Pop = Int
type TotalPop = [Pop]
type City = (Name, (Coordinates, TotalPop))

testData :: [City]
testData = [("New York City", ((1,1), [5, 4, 3, 2])),
           ("Washingotn DC", ((3,3), [3, 2, 1, 1])),
           ("Los Angeles", ((2,2), [7, 7, 7, 5]))]

getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Int
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = head ([ z !! (yearIn - 1) | (x,z) <- lookup nameIn cs])
```

**Expected behaviour**:

```hs
getCityPopulation testData "New York City" 2
>>> 4
```

**Actual behaviour**:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[(a0, [Int])]’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe (Coordinates, TotalPop)’
    • In the expression: lookup nameIn cs
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: (x, z) <- lookup nameIn cs
      In the first argument of ‘head’, namely
        ‘([z !! (yearIn - 1) | (x, z) <- lookup nameIn cs])’
   |
55 | getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = head ([ z !! (yearIn - 1) | (x,z) <- lookup nameIn cs])
   |                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Lookup returns a `Maybe City` since that can fail.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What would be the solution to get the expected output?

Comment: What is the expected output if you type `getCityPopulation testData "New York City" 2000`? What about `getCityPopulation testData "Boston" 2`?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It should say something like `Data unavailable, check inputs again`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Int
getCityPopulation [] nameIn yearIn = error "Can't be empty"
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = 
   head ([ z !! (yearIn - 1) | (x,z) <- maybeToList $ lookup nameIn cs])
```

does the job. This uses

```
maybeToList :: Maybe a -> [a]   -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
```

which is needed to transform the output of

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

Of course that code should actually be

```
   head ([ z !! (yearIn - 1) | (x,z) <- maybeToList $ lookup nameIn cs])
 ==
   case (lookup nameIn cs) of 
      Just (x,z) ->  z !! (yearIn - 1)
      Nothing    ->  error "couldn't find it"
```

so that

```
> getCityPopulation testData "New York City" 2
4

> getCityPopulation testData "Las Vegas" 2
*** Exception: couldn't find it
```

but writing a code that can fail like that is also not right. It is better to again wrap the result in a `Maybe`:

```
getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Maybe Int
getCityPopulation [] nameIn yearIn = error "Can't be empty"
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = 
   case (lookup nameIn cs) of 
      Just (x,z) ->  Just $ z !! (yearIn - 1)
      Nothing    ->  Nothing
```

and then we have

```
> getCityPopulation testData "New York City" 2
Just 4

> getCityPopulation testData "Las Vegas" 2
Nothing
```

Now, having changed the output type, we can actually go back to the original code -- *almost*:

```
getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Maybe Int
getCityPopulation [] nameIn yearIn = error "Can't be empty"
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = 
   [ z !! (yearIn - 1) | (x,z) <- lookup nameIn cs]
```

What magic is this, you ask? It is known as `MonadComprehensions`. You turn it on either at GHCi prompt with

```
> :set -XMonadComprehensions
```

or by including

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}
```

*pragma* at the top of your source file.

There's [no magic fix](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20Int%20-%3E%20Maybe%20a) though for the possible out-of-bounds access problem that your code has, using that `!!` without checking. Or is there?

```
getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Maybe Int
getCityPopulation [] nameIn yearIn = error "Can't be empty"
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = 
   [ e | (_,z) <- lookup nameIn cs, 
         e <- listToMaybe $ drop (yearIn-1) z ]
```

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Haskell, what does the `$` do?

Comment: `f $ x === f ( x )`

Answer (score 2):

[**`lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) returns a `Maybe b`, not a list of `b`s that matched. In case it does not find a key in the list of tuples, `Nothing` is returned, otherwise it is a `Just somecity`.

```
getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Int
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = … (lookup nameIn cs)
```

Now that we have a `Maybe City`, we have to decide what to do in case of a `Nothing`, we can for example return `-1` in that case. For that we can use a *catamorphism* of the `Maybe` type: [**`maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe), here we can thus specify what to do in case of a `Nothing`, and we pass a function what to do in case of a `Just x` with the `x`:

```
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Int
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = maybe (-1) (…) (lookup nameIn cs)
```

Now the `…` is a `City` and we need to retrieve the year, we can use [**`snd :: (a, b) -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:snd) to obtain the list of the population, and then look up the relevant population, so:

```
import Data.Maybe(maybe)

getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Int
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = maybe (-1) ((!! yearIn) . snd) (lookup nameIn cs)
```

Returning a simple `Int` is however not very "*Haskellish*" for a computation that can fail, typically in that case the return type is a `Maybe Int` if the result should be an `Int` but can fail. We can work with [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to map the value wrapped in the `Just` data constructor, or use `Nothing` if we map over a `Nothing`, so then the function looks like:

```
getCityPopulation :: [City] -> Name -> Int -> Maybe Int
getCityPopulation cs nameIn yearIn = fmap ((!! yearIn) . snd) (lookup nameIn cs)
```

We then obtain for example:

```
Prelude> getCityPopulation testData "New York" 2
Nothing
Prelude> getCityPopulation testData "New York City" 2
Just 3
```

The `(!!)` function is also not very safe, since it is possible that the `yearIn` has a value that is less than `0` or greater than or equal to the length of the list of populations. I leave it as an exercise to implement a more safer varint.